# Does Simple HTML Dom support :has like parsing?

Tags: php, html, dom, xml-parsing, simple-html-dom

I have to parse an HTML structure like this:

```
<div class='container>
    <div class='inner-div'>
        <span class='text'>...</span>
        <div class='author'>
            <span data-author='Alpha'>...</span>
        </div>
        <div class='summary'>
            <span data-summary='Exclusive'>Text 1</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='inner-div'>
        <span class='text'>...</span>
        <div class='author'>
            <span data-author='Beta'>...</span>
        </div>
        <div class='summary'>
            <span data-summary='Non-Exclusive'>Text 2</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='inner-div'>
        <span class='text'>...</span>
        <div class='author'>
            <span data-author='Gamma'>...</span>
        </div>
        <div class='summary'>
            <span data-summary='Exclusive'>Text 3</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='inner-div'>
        <span class='text'>...</span>
        <div class='author'>
            <span data-author='Delta'>...</span>
        </div>
        <div class='summary'>
            <span data-summary='Non-Exclusive'>Text 4</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    ...
    <div class='inner-div'>
        <span class='text'>...</span>
        <div class='author'>
            <span data-author='Zeta'>...</span>
        </div>
        <div class='summary'>
            <span data-summary='Exclusive'>Text 5</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I wish to obtain the first 'Exclusive' summary where author is not 'Alpha'. In the above example it would be 'Text 3'. How can I parse this using Simple HTML DOM or even XML DOM?

ADDENDUM: I am looking for parsing the HTML using PHP Simple HTML Dom library. I know how to parse it in jQuery, but Simple HTML Dom library doesn't seem to support any equivalent for (:has).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, but here's a [simple html dom replacement that](https://github.com/monkeysuffrage/advanced_html_dom) does (you want `:not` instead of `:has` btw):

```
include_once('advanced_html_dom.php');

$html = str_get_html($str);

echo $html->find('.author:not(> [data-author=Alpha]) ~ .summary > [data-summary=Exclusive]', 0);
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing info on advanced_html_dom. Will test it, and hope that it is as quick as SHD for simple parsing. Marking this as the accepted answer. Keeping my own answer available in case someone wants to achieve this in simple_html_dom only.

Comment: Looks like AHD is broken for many selectors. Have to stick to SHD for now.

Comment: Broken for actual css selectors? I don't think so but you should open an issue if you do.

Comment: I am getting null for
    $html->find('div.container div.summary')

Comment: I see, it's because your `.container` tag is broken. Simple may be more forgiving of things like that.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, solved it on my own. For anyone looking for a solution, here is what I did.

```
$node = $html->find("span[data-summary='Exclusive']",0);
if ($node->parent()->parent()->find('div.author span',0)['data-author'] == 'Alpha') {
    $node = $html->find("span[data-summary='Exclusive']",1);
}
return $node->innertext;
```